# sheet.getRow(rowIndex) returns NULL - APACHE POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using the APACHE POI library to read an excel file in xlsx format.

My problem is that I want to remove the last row from each sheet of this excel, I found a way to find the last row to remove, but it returns an int. The method sheet.removeRow(Row var1); would solve my problem.

Well, having the row number that I want to delete and a method to delete that row. I just need to convert the lastRow (int) in a Row type so I can use the sheet.removeRow method.

To do that I used the following code: Row a = sheet.getRow(lastRow) this method should return a Row with that index. But instead it returns NULL.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or how to convert the line number I want to remove into a Row type?

Appreciate your help!

Here is an excerpt of the code that read my excel file

```
    public static List<Measure> excelToMeasures(InputStream is, ProjectMeasureFile projectMeasureFile) throws IOException {

    List<Measure> measures = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is)) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);

            int lastRow = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() -1;

            removeRow(sheet, lastRow);

            int rowNumber = 0;
            for (Row row : sheet) {

                // skip header
                if (rowNumber == 0) {
                    rowNumber++;
                    continue;
                }

                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.iterator();
                List<Cell> cellObject = new ArrayList<>();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    cellObject.add(cellIterator.next());
                }

                if (cellObject.size() > 0) {
                    Measure measure = new Measure();
                    measure.setArea(sheet.getSheetName());
                    measure.setCode(convertStringCell(cellObject.get(0)));
                    measure.setBehavior(convertStringCell(cellObject.get(1)));

                    measure.setHumanDependencyFactor(convertNumericCell(cellObject.get(2)));
                    Double measureType = convertToPercentage(measure.getHumanDependencyFactor());
                    measure.setHumanDependencyFactor(measureType);

                    measure.setMeasurementResults(convertNumericCell(cellObject.get(3)));
                    Double value = convertToPercentage(measure.getMeasurementResults());
                    measure.setMeasurementResults(value);

                    measure.setProjectMeasureFile(projectMeasureFile);
                    measures.add(measure);
                }

                rowNumber++;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("An error occurred when trying to parse the file.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return measures;
}
```

And here is the method for removing a row:

```
  public static void removeRow(Sheet sheet, int rowIndex) {
    int lastRowNum = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() -1;

    if (rowIndex == lastRowNum) {
        Row removingRow = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        Row a = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        if (removingRow != null) {

           
            System.out.println(sheet.getRow(lastRowNum).getCell(0).toString());
           
            sheet.removeRow(removingRow); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At first to title of your question: `Sheet.getRow` will return `NULL` by design. It returns `NULL` if the row behind the row index is not stored in sheet. So you always need to check for `NULL` after `Sheet.getRow`. Same is for `Row.getCell` which returns `NULL` by design for cells which are not stored in the row.

And `Sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows` is not the correct way to get the last row in sheet.

A `Excel` sheet only physically contains rows having cells stored in them. Rows which are completely empty are not physically stored. So if a sheet only contains data in rows 1, 2, 5, 6 and 7, then `Sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows` will return 5 but last row is 7.

There is `Sheet.getLastRowNum` to get the last row number (0-based) in sheet. So that would return 6 in the example above and `sheet.getRow(6)` would get the last row and not `NULL`.

But there is another problem to consider. In `Excel` rows might not be totally empty but only contains cells which are blank. Blank cells might be stored because they have cell formats or they had content before. `Sheet.getLastRowNum` gets the last **stored** row, even if this row only contains blank cells. So you need to check whether the row behind `Sheet.getLastRowNum` contains only blank cells  by iterating over the cells and check for `CellType.BLANK` if you need the last **filled** row.

The following method gets the last filled row in a sheet. It returns `NULL` if no filled row was found.

```
 Row getLastFilledRow(Sheet sheet) {
  int lastStoredRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
  for (int r = lastStoredRowNum; r >= 0; r--) {
   Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
   if (row != null) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
     if (cell.getCellType() != CellType.BLANK) return row;  
    }
   }       
  }
  return null;  
 }
```